# Safari 5.1 overrides Cmd-arrows for history even when I have them set otherwise

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, safari

For years, I have had custom Application keyboard Shortcuts set up for Safari, using Cmd plus the left and right arrows to navigate through tabs.

I just upgraded to Safari 5.1, and for some reason it has taken over these shortcuts to be equivalent to Back and Forward in the history. This is despite the *actual* shortcuts for Back and Forward being Cmd-[ and Cmd-] . Even if I override the Back/Forward shortcuts explicitly to something else, it still won't let go of its death grip on my trusted tab navigation combos.

Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just finished my extension to fix that problem.

You can find it at: https://github.com/troyanov/tabCmdSwitchFix